# How do I get dependencies for a vcpkg package before installing said package?

Tags: c++, dependencies, package-managers, vcpkg

I couldn't find a better way to word the title, so let me explain.

I'm using vcpkg for a project that requires OpenCV, so at some point before building my project I need to do `vcpkg install opencv`. That part is easy. The problem is what happens when you run `vcpkg install opencv`. OpenCV has it's own dependencies that I need to install before installing. Otherwise, you get a build error from vcpkg, so I can't just run the command and have OpenCV. Instead, I have to do:

1. Run `vcpkg install opencv`
2. Check for build errors.
3. Install missing dependencies.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 until there are no more missing dependencies and everything builds.

This is a huge pain. Best case scenario, vcpkg should just install what it needs somewhere, but I would gladly settle for being able to do `sudo apt install <ALL dependencies> && vcpkg install <package>`. The question is where can I find that list of "ALL dependencies" for a package.

Comment: If there are build errors because of missing dependencies I believe this is a bug in the opencv port file for vcpkg, You should file a bug report. vcpkg is supposed to build all of the dependent libraries before it builds a package.

Comment: That's what I would have thought, but I've run across a few similar github issues where they were eventually closed because "It's not a bug. You just have to install this thing first."
https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/21524#issuecomment-984366235

Answer (score 3):

The command to [recursively] view dependencies of a package with vcpkg
is `depend-info <package-name>`:

```
>vcpkg depend-info llfio

vcpkg-cmake:
vcpkg-cmake-config:
ned14-internal-quickcpplib: vcpkg-cmake, vcpkg-cmake-config
status-code: vcpkg-cmake, vcpkg-cmake-config
outcome: ned14-internal-quickcpplib, status-code, vcpkg-cmake, vcpkg-cmake-config
llfio: outcome, vcpkg-cmake, vcpkg-cmake-config
```

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question. You answered the question on how to see which dependencies vcpkg itself will build in the process of building a port (llfio) but not what system dependencies are required to do so (e.g. libmesa, libx11 and so on) which this question is about.